# RDS Mysql connection Slow

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, rds

I'm experiencing a strange behabvior with Amazon RDS.

In fact I was using RDS on a db.t2.large instance. And an auto-scaling group of EC2's connecting and writing data to the database.

When there is more traffic to proccess (**800 query per second**), some php processes take to much time to connect to the database.

I checked and identified that the problem happens just at the connection to the database, in the mysqli classconstrutor (**__construct**).

The fonction taking too longtime (more than 8seconds sometimes) is this :

`$this->mysqli = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database'], $config['port']);`

So myqli takes **8 sencondes** to instantiate a new mysql connection.

I then tought it's the rds db instane eb mater, and decide to upgrade the  instance, and bring the instance from t2.large to m4.xlarge.
When I did that the of request before my application become slow doubled, connexions becomes slow taking **8 secondes** to connect to the database when we reach **1600 query per second**.

I have searched all the way and nothng. When the connection is so slaw, the rds instance does not have neither cpu consumption(**20%**), nor more connectiions in the console(**14**).

The problem is at the network/conection level.
Please can someon any idea?

Comment: have you solved this by any chance?

Comment: Not really solved, but the issue disapeared itself, maybe it was at AWS side.....